# Procedure to Upgrade SSD without borking-up MS-Office License

Tags: ssd, ms-office, upgrade

I have upgraded a Macbook 500GB to a 128GB SSD.  MS-Office 2011 detected the change and the licensing failed.  I would like to avoid this problem in the future if at all possible.

I would like to upgrade a 128GB Macbook air to 1TB: is it possible to create a 128GB partition to let Office think that it is on a 128GB drive and not bork-up the license?  If yes, how is it this done?

I am seeking to avoid dealing with licensing keys if at all possible and simply upgrade the SSD

Comment: I have mac Office 2011.  I have the product key.  Office fails to accept this key and gave me an 800 number to call.  After saying the right words, Microsoft employee give me a new number to enter.  PITA.

Comment: @historystamp - that's because it has to activate and the activation servers for Office 2011 products are no longer online (it's a dead product)

Comment: @historystamp  What do you mean with the term `right words`?

Comment: @gatorback Convince Microsoft you have a legal copy of Office.  I called microsoft in the last week to get a new key for Office since I was booting from a new external ssd.  No problem.  It was automated.  Didn't have to speak to a person as before.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t think so. I’m guessing MS makes a signature of your h/w. If you replace or add parts, your changing the signature. Hence the problems.

You should be able to reactivate your license.